# Combine xlst transformations into one

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a few xslt files that are used to modify an xml document. Metadata xml for ArcGIS Desktop 10.4. Currently I have them chained together to get the needed output xml (apply xslt 1 to the input xml, then apply xslt 2 to the output of step one, then apply xslt 3). While this works fine I would like to combine my three sheets into one. I have tried but each part "overwrites" the last when I combine them.

This removes all unneeded nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
   <!-- process the metadata using the templates below -->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- copy all metadata conent -->
   <xsl:template match="node() | @*" priority="0">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--  If the element exists, remove it -->
   <xsl:template match="resConst | Process | mdContact | citRespParty | idPoC | idCredit | prcStep | rpIndName | rpOrgName | rpPosName | role | displayName | rpCntInfo | searchKeys | themeKeys" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This adds some use limits.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
   <!-- process the metadata using the templates below -->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- copy all metadata conent -->
   <xsl:template match="node() | @*" priority="0">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- Add Nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="dataIdInfo">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*" />
         <resConst>
            <Consts>
               <useLimit>CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY INFORMATION</useLimit>
            </Consts>
         </resConst>
         <searchKeys>
            <keyword>keyword</keyword>
         </searchKeys>
         <themeKeys>
            <keyword>keyword</keyword>
         </themeKeys>
    <idCredit>our org</idCredit>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Lastly, this one adds a point of contact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
   <!-- process the metadata using the templates below -->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- copy all metadata conent -->
   <xsl:template match="node() | @*" priority="0">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- Add Nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="idCitation">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*" />
         <citRespParty>
            <rpIndName>name</rpIndName>
            <rpOrgName>org</rpOrgName>
            <rpPosName>role</rpPosName>
            <role>
               <RoleCd value="007" />
            </role>
            <rpCntInfo>
               <cntAddress addressType="">
                  <delPoint>street number</delPoint>
                  <city>city</city>
                  <adminArea>state</adminArea>
                  <postCode>zip</postCode>
                  <eMailAdd>email</eMailAdd>
                  <country>country</country>
               </cntAddress>
               <cntPhone>
                  <voiceNum tddtty="">phone number</voiceNum>
               </cntPhone>
            </rpCntInfo>
         </citRespParty>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input:
http://textuploader.com/d92rd

Sample output:
http://textuploader.com/d92r6

Example node change: You will see that resConsts is node is dropped in full. Then a new resConsts node is added at the same XPath with our org use limitation text.

This is Esri site that a based my process on:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/metadata/editing-metadata-for-many-arcgis-items.htm

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? It's usually considered good practice to do the opposite: break up a complex transformation into a pipeline of separate, simple, reusable steps.

Comment: No, I am not sure it is a good idea. I have never used xslt before. I was thinking it would be more efficient/professional to combine them. Right now I have them chained with python.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [XProc](https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/)

```
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" version="1.0">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:document href="input-file.xml"></p:document>
    </p:input>
    <p:output port="result"/>
    <p:xslt>
        <p:input port="stylesheet">
            <p:document href="sheet1.xsl"/>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="parameters">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:xslt>
    <p:xslt>
        <p:input port="stylesheet">
            <p:document href="sheet2.xsl"/>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="parameters">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:xslt>
    <p:xslt>
        <p:input port="stylesheet">
            <p:document href="sheet3.xsl"/>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="parameters">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:xslt>

</p:declare-step>
```

or some processor specific chaining (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html with `saxon:next-in-chain`).

If you want to merge the three stylesheet by hand into one stylesheet then learn about using [modes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes) and set them up:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resConst | Process | mdContact | citRespParty | idPoC | idCredit | prcStep | rpIndName | rpOrgName | rpPosName | role | displayName | rpCntInfo | searchKeys | themeKeys" 
 mode="step1"/>

   <xsl:template match="dataIdInfo" mode="step2">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*" />
         <resConst>
            <Consts>
               <useLimit>CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY INFORMATION</useLimit>
            </Consts>
         </resConst>
         <searchKeys>
            <keyword>keyword</keyword>
         </searchKeys>
         <themeKeys>
            <keyword>keyword</keyword>
         </themeKeys>
    <idCredit>our org</idCredit>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="step1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="step2">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1/node()" mode="step2"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$step2/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="idCitation">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*" />
         <citRespParty>
            <rpIndName>name</rpIndName>
            <rpOrgName>org</rpOrgName>
            <rpPosName>role</rpPosName>
            <role>
               <RoleCd value="007" />
            </role>
            <rpCntInfo>
               <cntAddress addressType="">
                  <delPoint>street number</delPoint>
                  <city>city</city>
                  <adminArea>state</adminArea>
                  <postCode>zip</postCode>
                  <eMailAdd>email</eMailAdd>
                  <country>country</country>
               </cntAddress>
               <cntPhone>
                  <voiceNum tddtty="">phone number</voiceNum>
               </cntPhone>
            </rpCntInfo>
         </citRespParty>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Typed in the browser and untested, but should show the principle.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried but each part "overwrites" the last when I combine them.

Without seeing an example of the input, we can only guess why this happens. My guess is that you are using some templates to **copy** nodes to which you should apply other templates instead. Copying a node writes it directly to the result tree - out of reach of the other templates.

If my guess is correct, then you only need to change all occurrences of:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  remove selected elements (and their descendants) -->
<xsl:template match="resConst | Process | mdContact | citRespParty | idPoC | idCredit | prcStep | rpIndName | rpOrgName | rpPosName | role | displayName | rpCntInfo | searchKeys | themeKeys" />

<!-- add nodes to dataIdInfo -->
<xsl:template match="dataIdInfo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        <resConst>
            <Consts>
                <useLimit>CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY INFORMATION</useLimit>
            </Consts>
        </resConst>
        <searchKeys>
            <keyword>keyword</keyword>
        </searchKeys>
        <themeKeys>
            <keyword>keyword</keyword>
        </themeKeys>
        <idCredit>our org</idCredit>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add nodes to idCitation -->
<xsl:template match="idCitation">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        <citRespParty>
            <rpIndName>name</rpIndName>
            <rpOrgName>org</rpOrgName>
            <rpPosName>role</rpPosName>
            <role>
                <RoleCd value="007" />
            </role>
            <rpCntInfo>
                <cntAddress addressType="">
                    <delPoint>street number</delPoint>
                    <city>city</city>
                    <adminArea>state</adminArea>
                    <postCode>zip</postCode>
                    <eMailAdd>email</eMailAdd>
                    <country>country</country>
                </cntAddress>
                <cntPhone>
                    <voiceNum tddtty="">phone number</voiceNum>
                </cntPhone>
            </rpCntInfo>
        </citRespParty>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sorry I added a very striped down input xml. And yes I am trying to copy all nodes. Then I need to remove a few nodes and then add some new ones. Sometimes an added node may have existed before the nodes are removed.

Comment: Please add also the expected result and explain how it differs from the result produced by the suggested stylesheet.

Comment: "*Sometimes an added node may have existed before the nodes are removed.*" I am afraid I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Uploaded the input and output files to a text host. I am afraid that they are too many lines for the post. I also outlined how one node is changed. The resConst is removed in the fist xslt and then added back in with step 2 xslt.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying. And I don't have time to hunt through all of that for differences. Please pinpoint the problem - if it exists. AFAICT, the existing `resConst` should be removed and a new `resConst` element should be added - which is exactly what my stylesheet does.